# Retaining text in Master Page textbox across content pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

I have a master page with a text box for entering a date. 3 content pages use this master page, and show different data according to the date entered. Now, when the user switches from one content page to another, I want to retain the date in the textbox. Is it possible to do that without using cookies, session state and query string?

Comment: What is the problem with query string or sessions?

Comment: I just wanted to know if there is a better way of doing that, no problem with query string or sessions as such.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly sure that you can use the master's `ViewState` to store the value since it is independent of the ContentPage's ViewState.

So you can set the `TextBox.Text` in `Page_load` and write the `ViewState` in `MasterPage.PreRender`.